# Extracting value from JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have extracted data from another website which is in JSON format - here is what I extracted: http://sub7legends.net/crawler.php

I need to get the value of kills and deaths from this.
I tried `json_decode()` in php of this data but when I var_dump() the result it just says "NULL".

What can I do to extract the required data?

Comment: The link works for me. according to jsonlint the output is no valid json, hence the `null` from json_decode().

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski I just fixed the link would you mind looking again

Comment: It is a really long json, and something in the server (php? apache? other?) is cutting down the json output.

Answer (score 0):

The link doesn't work for me. But if you have a normal json just like this one:

```
{"kills": "5", "deaths": "3"}
```

Then the `json_decode()` method should work.
Here would be a sample code snippet:

```
$json_you_got_from_the_server = '{"kills": "5", "deaths": "3"}';
$result = json_decode($json_you_got_from_the_server);
$kills = $result->kills;
$deaths = $result->deaths;
echo "You have ".$kills." kills and ".$deaths." deaths.";
```

I haven't tried it, but it should work. If it doesn't, then please comment and I will try something else.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, The link was a problem on my side. I fixed it now. The json is a little more tricky than that. Would you mind trying again now with the working link

Answer (score 0):

the current json contents are not valid, try validating it first. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can validate it? Or know any other way I can extract the kills

Comment: Hers is another one jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

That json in the link you have pasted has no proper ending scroll to the end and you will see. If this is the same thing that you wanted to parse then it will always return null.